# Knowing when Google Analytics has loaded when loaded via Google Tag Manager

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager

We're using GTM to load Universal Analytics and I want to send some custom events from js to GA.
So I need to do something like this:

```
ga('send', {
    hitType: 'event',
    eventCategory: 'Legitimation',
    eventAction: 'Is returning customer',
    nonInteraction: true
});
```

But I don't know when GA has loaded since GTM makes everything async.
How can I know when ga() is ready?

Comment: The ga object has a property called answer that is set to 42 when ga is loaded. So you could have a timer or a promise that listens to that property. However this is a horrible idea for your use case and you should stick to the answer given by Daniel.

Answer (score 4):

Sending GA Events not through the Tag Manager if you load GA through the GTM is a little bit tricky. You can´t use the normal events you use if you have GA hardcoded on the Page.

Here is a good thread about this - also answering your question: https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/tag-manager/C2j4nt8dBxw

I would suggest to send Datalayers instead of Events, catch this Datalayers with the GTM and send the Events through the GTM. This makes it a lot easier.

Comment: Do I have to setup all individual events in gtm?

Comment: No one Event in the GTM would be enough. 
You could build your datalayer like this:
  dataLayer = [{
    'eventCategory': '{{YourValue}}',
    'eventAction': '{{YourValue}}'
    'event': 'Your_event_name'
  }];

Now build a Data Layer Variable in GTM listening on f.e. eventCategory
Add this Variable in a Event in the GTM - Trigger Event = Your_event_name 
In this case you just need one Event in the GTM for all your GA Events

Comment: Ok, so I set up a Custom Event variable in GTM 
and I am pushing to dataLayer with: dataLayer.push({'event': 'Legitimation', 'eventAction': 'Is returning customer'}); 
With the preview I can see GTM is catching the event but nothing comes up in when I look in GA under Real-time Events.

Comment: Hm that seems to be a other problem. Are the Events empty or didn´t GTM fired the events? Can you check your normal reports for the events?

Comment: Did you configure GTM event tags, triggered with the `event` called `Legitimation`? You won't see events unless you create and configure their tags.

Comment: I'm very late here, but I find this article very helpful to set up GA & GTM event bypass: https://mixedanalytics.com/blog/ga-gtm-event-tracking-pass-through-datalayer/